# Forcing a horizontal scrollbar in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I have a client that wants a scrollbar on top of their content.  So I made an empty div, placed it on top of the real content, added a scroll bar and bound the scrolling of the fake div and the empty one together using javascript.  This all works great in every browser... except IE8.  IE8 doesn't show my scrollbar in my empty div (technically it has an `&nbsp;` in it) no matter what I try.

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cwolves/NShGP/

```
<div class="mock-scroller">
    <div class="mock-content" style="width:2000px;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>

.mock-scroller {
    position   : absolute;
    top        : 0px;
    left       : 0px;
    width      : 274px;
    height     : 20px;
    overflow-x : auto;
    overflow-y : hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps `overflow-x : scroll;`?

[image: works on my machine]

Comment: Unfortunately I'm just not set up to test IE <9.

Comment: ... thanks, but no.  IE8-specific issue, no matter what I do to the overflow, the scrollbar won't show up.

Comment: @Matt Ball - if you have IE9 you have IE developer tools and can switch back to IE8 rendering mode :)

Comment: yeah, that's what I'm looking at too, except I don't see a scrollbar

Comment: I'm on Windows 7, FWIW. Ain't IE support just _grand_

Comment: Something else to try: `overflow: scroll; overflow-y: hidden;`

Comment: okay, for what it's worth -- on my machine I had to raise the height to `25px` and set `overflow:scroll`.  Without `overflow:scroll`, the height had to be raised to 37px...  So I raised it to 40 to be safe since the design allows it... I ___HATE___ IE

Comment: +infinity for the last bit. I feel your pain.